# Select a list of all game titles bought by those who have purchased a specified game

Tags: sql

I want to select the list of games purchased by players who bought 'this_game'

Here is my base of 3 tables :

```
PLAYERS(IDP INT PK, PSEUDO VARCHAR)
GAMES(IDG INT PK, TITLE VARCHAR)
SALES(IDP INT FK, IDG INT FK)
```

I've tried something like that but it's not correct:

```sql
SELECT TITLE from SALES
JOIN GAMES on SALES.IDG = GAMES.IDG
JOIN PLAYERS on SALES.IDP = PLAYERS.IDP
GROUP BY TITLE
HAVING TITLE= 'this_game'
```

I've tried different things but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a join on all 3 tables:

```
select distinct g.title
from games g
inner join sales s on s.idg = g.idg
inner join players p on p.idp = s.idp
where p.idp in (
  select s.idp 
  from sales s inner join games g
  on g.idg = s.idg 
  where g.title = 'this_game'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `players` table to solve this -- nor a subquery, although that is not a problem:

```
select distinct g2.title
from games g1 join
     sales s1
     on g1.idg = s1.idg and
        g1.title = 'this game' join
     sales s2
     on s1.idp = s2.idp join  -- same person
     games g2
     on g2.idg = s2.idg;
```